# Incompatible types when assigning

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following code, which I read and read many times and it always appears to be okay, but the compiler says:

> error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct Type[10]'
>   from type 'Type'

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
} Type;

typedef struct
{
    Type (*typeArray)[10];
} Type2;


void someFunction(Type2 *type2Variable, Type (*typeArray)[10])
{
    Type typeNewValue;

    type2Variable->typeArray[0] = typeNewValue;  /* This throws the error */
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Type typeArray[10];
    Type2 type2Variable;

    someFunction(&type2Variable, &typeArray);
}
```

I'm sure the solution is just a `*` somewhere but I can't find it.

**Update**

Thanks a lot for your answers, this was just a non-sense example to show my problem (this isn't the real code).

The solution was:

```
(*type2Variable->typeArray)[0] = typeNewValue;
```

Instead of:

```
type2Variable->typeArray[0] = typeNewValue;
```

Comment: Sorry, check it out now.

Comment: lhs is `Type[10]`, rhs is `Type`. What is surprising?

Comment: I'm trying to modify the value of `typeArray[10]`. Yes, I know that works, but why? `typeArray` is defined as `[10]` not `[10][10]`.

Comment: Anyway, will you add a question to your post anytime soon?

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense, what are you trying to do?

Comment: change to `(*type2Variable->typeArray)[0] = typeNewValue;`, but not allocate.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY That code will do an illegal dereference.

Comment: @this ; you misunderstood it.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY `type2Variable->typeArray` doesn't point anywhere, and you dereference it.

Comment: @this I advised already.

Comment: @this , need `type2Variable->typeArray = typeArray;` before it. Maybe :)

Answer (score 1):

`Type (*typeArray)[10]` declares a *pointer* to an array of size 10 of the type `Type`. It seems that you want do declare a array of `Type`:

```
typedef struct
{
  Type typeArray[10];
} Type2;

void someFunction(Type2 *type2Variable, Type * typeArray) { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign a single `Type` where a `Type[10]` is expected, and that is exactly what the compiler is complaining about.  You would have to change the `Type2::typeArray` member from `Type (*typeArray)[10];` to `Type typeArray[10];` for that assignment to work.

Comment: Sorry, but where did I use `Type2::typeArray`?

Comment: On the line you say is erroring: `type2Variable->typeArray[0] = typeNewValue;`  `typeNewValue` is a single `Type`, but that is not what `typeArray[0]` is expecting, hence the error.

Comment: tagged and post content are in C, not C++  (Type2::typeArray  ?)

Answer (score 0):

***The names you are choosing for arguments are helping to confuse things.***
The way your code is written, your error on the line indicated

```
type2Variable->typeArray[0] = typeNewValue;  /* This throws the error */
```

is because it should be written:

```
type2Variable->typeArray = typeArray;  /* to match argument name */
```

***Look at the argument here:***

```
//                                             V-------V
void someFunction(Type2 *type2Variable, Type (*typeArray)[10])
{
    Type typeNewValue, *pTypeNewValue;

    pTypeNewValue = &typeNewValue;

    type2Variable->typeArray = typeArray; //No longer throws error 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change to

```
void someFunction(Type2 *type2Variable, Type (*typeArray)[10])
{
    Type typeNewValue;//uninitialized
    type2Variable->typeArray = typeArray;//maybe :) But for what.
    (*type2Variable->typeArray)[0] = typeNewValue;
}
```

Comment: Some explanation would be nice!

Comment: explanation... I do not know that  he doing this for anything.

Comment: What happens result, set uninitialize value(as `struct Type`) to `typeArray[0]` at main.,